# What are "secret" hats?

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash

I've been awarded two "secret hats" this week.  What are there significance, if anything?  I've got one that says IG-88 and another that says Johnny Three-Hats.  The FAQ is intentionally vague on secret hats, saying that if it explained it, it wouldn't be much of a secret.  Will I ever know what the secret was?

Comment: Oh, and here I was hoping that you could tell us what that thing on your head is. :-)  (You're the only person I've seen with IG-88 and I don't recognize the reference.)

Comment: On MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211707, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212305

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I figured out the IG-88 hat secret.  IG-88 was a robot assassin in the Star Wars. See http://www.google.com/imgres?sa=X&biw=917&bih=588&tbm=isch&tbnid=g8fVCINs-dsteM:&imgrefurl=http://readandreact.net/tag/ig-88/&docid=6UtbEazj3-DAWM&imgurl=http://readandreact.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/ig-88.jpg&w=250&h=375&ei=Oom0UorJAoqfkQex7oCAAg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:10,s:0,i:111&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=164&tbnw=104&start=0&ndsp=16&tx=59&ty=89  I assume that it has something to do with my review activity and votes to delete posts.

Answer (score 6):

If we told you, then it wouldn't be a secret :) All I can say is there are hats that weren't announced, and are unlocked in mysterious ways. Figuring out how you (or anyone else) managed to unlock one is part of the fun!

Spoilers do exist, but I recommend not reading them until after the contest. I participated in last year's Winter Bash as a user, and it was really fun. This year has also been a lot of fun for me, but it would have been more fun if I didn't know what they all were and how they are awarded.

They'll be announced at the end, worry not :)

Comment: FTR they were announced here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/